# Should the WebInfo file be excluded from SVN

Tags: asp.net, svn, file

I have recently had a few issues when checking out a colleagues ASP.NET project, that causes the Project to get into a conflicted state because of the WEBINFO file being checked into SVN.

Does this file need to be in the repository or should we exclude it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I think *.webinfo* should be excluded. (Some info about webinfo: [How to copy and configure ASP.NET projects between different local computers](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/VSNETcopyproject.aspx?display=PrintAll&fid=162397&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&fr=26))